# 'market survey' OR 'marketing survey'

Tags: word-choice

*Market survey* or *marketing survey?*

When you ask somebody to answer your questions, which term is correct?

Comment: They refer to two different things. What research have you attempted thus far?

Comment: As appropriate and applicable to the context.

Comment: They are completely different.  Glance in any **business dictionary**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Market Survey

Typically implies research about a specific "market", for example, 'electric cars', or a niche like 'jewelry-encrusted watches'. The Entrepreneur magazine provides a [narrower definition](http://www.entrepreneur.com/encyclopedia/market-surveys), specific to the needs of budding entrepreneurs.

Also synonymous to **market research survey**.

### Marketing Survey

Historically refers to feedback solicitation from customers about the effectiveness of a company or organization's marketing. More recently though, it has become synonymous to market research survey and is no longer the exclusive domain of an organization's marketing branch.

### Verdict: Market Survey > Marketing Survey

According to [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=market%20survey%2Cmarketing%20survey&year_start=1910&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmarket%20survey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmarketing%20survey%3B%2Cc0), "market survey" trumps "marketing survey":
• If you look at the [1910-1980 time period](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=market%20survey%2Cmarketing%20survey&year_start=1910&year_end=1980&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmarket%20survey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmarketing%20survey%3B%2Cc0), **market survey** was blowing **marketing survey** out of the water.
• More recently, however, [since 1980](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=market%20survey%2Cmarketing%20survey&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmarket%20survey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmarketing%20survey%3B%2Cc0), **market survey** has become less popular but is still more common than **marketing survey**.

Answer (score 0):

### Market Survey

Surveying your market.

### Marketing Survey

A survey conducted for marketing purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I`ve figured it out.